# How to update row with the contents of that specific row + new data

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have approx. 60000 rows with street address in my db that contain short version of the
actual street address eg.

```
Svarvarg. 11
Kungsg. 10
Stora g. 19
```

"**g.**" is a abbreviation of "**gatan**" and this creates problems within my application.
So what I want do to is to Select all rows that contain "**g.**" and replace "**g.**" with "**gatan**"
Eg.

```
Svarvarg. 11 -> Svarvargatan 11
Kungsg. 10 -> Kungsgatan 10
Stora g. 19 -> Stora gatan 19
```

The selection of all street address that contain "**g.**" is simple but I can't figure out how to do the replacement in SQL. Could you please help me with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use

```
UPDATE table SET column = REPLACE(column, 'g.', 'gatan') WHERE ...
```

See this documentation http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace

Comment: Thank you, you were first! SQL STATEMENT: UPDATE Company SET streetAddress = REPLACE(streetAddress, 'g. ', 'gatan ') WHERE streetAddress LIKE "%g.%";

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
update table
set ColumnName = replace(ColumnName, 'g.', 'gatan')
where ColumnName like '%g.%'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE Foo SET Street = REPLACE(Street, 'g. ', 'gatan ')
```